# Pause in the program for some time

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c, time, millis

I have a variable `timeInSec` which records the time as loop begins. It is defined as `timeInSec = millis();`. I have two conditions. If `(timeInSec - lastRun)< 5` (that is 5 sec) , the first condition is executed(the if statement).Otherwise if `(timeInSec - lastRun)>5` the second condition is executed(else statement). Here is the code:

```
void loop(){
  timeInSec = millis();  // Records time in seconds
  // if(lastRun > 0) {   // if i run this, only else statement is executed
  // delay(10000);
  // }
  if((timeInSec - lastRun) < 5000){  // Treshold time (if condition which runs when timeInSec is less than 5 seconds)
    // Some code
  }
  else{ // If treshold time exceeds (executes when timeInSec is > 5seconds)
   delay(10000);  // if i run this, only else statement is executed
   lastRun = timeInSec;
  }
}
```

Here the `else` statement executes once and control goes back `if` statement again. I want to pause the control at `else` statement for 10 seconds and then go back to `if` statement for further execution. Everytime  the control should pause at `else` statement for 10 seconds. I have used `delay` in the `else` statement and in this case only `else` statement is being executed. The same happens if I use `delay` at the start of loop (as in code). I have tried without using `delay` but didn't succeed.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to change `millis()`. Instead, record the last time the
second code (else statement) ran, and check whether that was more than
five seconds ago:

```
void loop() {
    static uint32_t lastRun;
    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (now - lastRun < 5000) {
        // Some code
    }
    else {
        // Some code
        lastRun = now;  // record the time
    }
}
```

This is essentially the same technique used in the [Blink without
delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino
tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code works perfect. I have a small doubt here. If I keep a delay at the start of `else` code say `delay(2000);` , only the `else` statement runs continuously instead of going to `if` statement. If I remove the `delay` in `else`, the code works perfect. Please tell me the reason. I need the compiler to stop in `else` statement (after execution) for 2 seconds and then go to `if` statement. I have used the delay in `else` statement but it didn't work. To achieve the same I have typed `if(lastRun>0){delay(2000);}` ,but it didn't work.

Comment: @SriHarsha: Do not use the comments to ask new questions. You can either write a new question or, if you believe this really belongs to the same question, edit that question.

Comment: @edgar-Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the question.

Comment: TLDR; try `else{ delay(2000); lastRun = millis(); }` instead. Using the `now` variable after a delay, will result in using the old time.

Comment: @Gerben-Thanks for the reply. It works perfect.